# java homework with word replacement

Tags: java

Hello can someone help me? The point of the homework is to read a file then create another file where it replaces all of the words "is" with "was", i have all this done but I am also not sopposed to replace words that have"is" in them, for example: "this, isthmus".

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


public class WordChange {
public static void main(String[]args) throws Exception {

    FileReader fr = null;
    FileWriter fw = null;

    try
         {
         Scanner keyboard=new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("Enter the name of the text file: ");
         String fileName=keyboard.nextLine();
         File file = new File(fileName);
         BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
         String line = "", oldtext = "";
         while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
             {

             oldtext += line + "\r\n";

         }
         reader.close();
         String replacedtext=oldtext.replaceAll("is ","was ");
         FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("output.txt");
         writer.write(replacedtext);


         writer.close();

     }
      catch (IOException ioe)
         {
         ioe.printStackTrace();
     }
}
```

}

Comment: It would be to your benefit if you were to clarify what parts specifically were giving you trouble.  What are you experiencing, what did you expect and what are you getting?

Comment: Sorry! I am still getting used to this website! I will keep that in mind in the future

Comment: Have a look at this: [ask] and this: [mcve] - it's helpful stuff!

Comment: Thanks @NateBarbettini!

Answer (score 1):

just a guess here but instead of

```
String replacedtext=oldtext.replaceAll("is ","was ");
```

would this work

```
String replacedtext=oldtext.replaceAll(" is "," was ");
```

Im just guessing let me know if it works

Comment: You're probably right, but we don't really know what the issue is that the OP is seeing.

Comment: haha thanks ! I cant believe I overlooked that! Thanks it did work!

Comment: No problem, I overlook small stuff like that a lot too.

Comment: and yea Makoto that why i said just a guess haha